# Sending json data through ajax to express server

Tags: json, ajax, node.js, express

I need to pass json data to the express server, this is code I used, on running it returns error 400(bad request).

```
// client side
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"/name",
    dataType: 'json',
        data: [{"name": "test"}],
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){
           alert("success");
           alert(data);
    }
});

// server side:
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());     
var name;
app.get('/name', function (req, res) {
    name= req.body.name;
    res.send(name);
});
```

Comment: You have app.get('/name') when it should be app.post('/name')

Answer (score 1):

You need to stringify your object

```
data: JSON.stringify([{"name": "test"}]),
```

what you probably want is just

```
data: JSON.stringify({"name": "test"}),
```

Comment: Not sure why setting the JSON would make it a 404.... Oh, you don't need that array...

Comment: still the same error. Am i missing something else ?

Comment: I think your endpoint has to be a full one like : url: 'http://localhost:3000/endpoint